# Вопрос по наследованию в Python 3. Наследование Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, наследование

Работаю с Selenium, хочу что бы класс Parser наследовал объект driver класса родителя Client.

```
class Client:
      options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
      def __init(self, proxy):
           self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
           self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
class Parser(Client):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
      def f(self):
          self.driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')
```

Дело в том что в такой конструкции создается новый объект driver.(новое окно в хроме на деле). А я хочу использовать именно тот уже созданный до этого объект.
Например рабочий вариант кода такой:

```
class Client:
      options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
      options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)

class Parser(Client):
      def f(self):
          self.driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')
```

Но мне нужно передавать разные прокси при создании объекта класса Client, а так же это просто не красиво и не правильно. Пожалуйста поясните за наследование в этом конкретном случае и как мне решить проблему грамотно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неверно поняли зачем нужно наследование. То, как вы хотите его использовать, это не ООП. `Client` и `Parser` это разные бизнес сущности, не следует одно наследовать от другого. `Client` - это интерфейс браузера, `Parser` - непосредственно объект, который пользуется этим интерфейсом, чтобы получить какую-то информацию из браузера.

Логичнее сделать так:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def open_url(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

class Parser:
  def __init__(self, client):
      self.client = client
  def open_so(self):
      self.client.open_url('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')

client = Client()
parser = Parser(client)
parser.open_so()
```

Если хотите использовать наследование, то можно реализовать базовый класс `Client`, и от него наследовать клиенты для конкретных браузеров: `ClientChrome`, `ClientFirefox`. В базовом можно хранить реализацию прокси (так как эта штука универсальная), а в дочерних создавать уже драйвера

Comment: Большое спасибо, я чувствовал что что то не так в понимании!!! =)

Comment: +1. Ну и вдогонку к вашему ответу могу посоветовать автору вопроса погуглить статьи на тему отличия наследования, композиции и агрегации.

Comment: @Александр спасибо большое, сейчас буду читать!

Comment: В примере @suit использует вид взаимодействия между классами - агрегация. Отличная статья https://habr.com/post/354046/